# Adding a catch to ignore machines that are not online

Tags: powershell

How would I add a catch to the script below so that it ignores machines that are not online?

Currently I am getting the following error message when a machine isn't online:

```
Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At C:\fcheck\run.ps1:6 char:9
+     gwmi <<<<  win32_operatingsystem -computername $hostname | ForEach-Object {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

This is my code so far:

```
$dict.Keys | foreach-object {
    $currKey = $_
    $dict[$_] | ForEach-Object {
        $PSObject = New-Object PSCustomObject | Select hostname, os, type
        $PSObject.hostname = $_
        $PSObject.os = Get-OS $_
        $PSObject.type = $currType
        $VMObjects += $PSObject
    }
}


$VMObjects | ft
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you attempt the action that results in the error, check that the computer is online.

```
if (test-connection -computername $hostname -quiet -count 1) {
# Run your process
} else {
# Computer is offline, do we need to do something different?
}
```

`Test-Connection` is available in PowerShell 2.0 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `Get-WmiObject` cmdlet, use set the error action flag as follows:

```
-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

this won't show any error when they're encountered.

Comment: Is there anyway to integrate it into my code as an if/else statement?

Comment: you wouldn't need to include this in an if/else statement. Just include it in the line of code when you call the Get-WmiObject.
I can't see the section in your script where you're calling Get-WmiObject so if you update your script I'll show you how to exactly use it.